# Magento 2 - Exception: File can't be read in Magento static content deploy

Tags: magento2, exception, static-content-deploy

Please tell me where is the problem.

I used `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US -f`

[image]

Comment: May be it's permission error. Please run : sudo chmod 777 -R pub/static from your root directory and then run command again

Comment: @NareshRupareliyaNR how to use this in windows ?

Comment: @NareshRupareliyaNR is not permission error

Comment: how can u identified that It's not permission issue?

Comment: @NareshRupareliyaNR in windows ? i don know how :(

Comment: run : **takeown /F pub\static** command using CLI in window from your root directory

Comment: SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "C:\wamp64\www\xxx\xx\pub\static" now owned by user "user".
I add this statement but I still have the error in the screenshot given

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not an issue with permission, this is issue with your custom theme less file. It means there is some type of error coming at the time of compiling from your custom theme less file. In this case, I would suggest, please try to disable/remove your custom theme and see if you are getting this issue or not. If you are not getting this issue then you need to check your custom theme less files and find out which file has typo error. You have to check and find out the file manually.